# Codebird php next cursor repeats results

Tags: php

I am stuck with a silly problem.I am trying to list my followers using codebird php (twitter api 1.1) and i get the results repeating every time:

```
public function getFollowers(){
     $this->client->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
     $fol=$this->client->followers_list();
     $cursor=-1;
     $cursor=$fol->next_cursor_str;
if($cursor > 0){
    $followers=(array)$this->client->followers_list('cursor=' . $cursor);
 //  var_dump($followers);
    }

     for($i=0;$i<count($followers) ;$i++){
          echo "<p>";
          echo "<img src=\"". $followers['users'][$i]->profile_image_url. "\" />";
          echo "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/". $followers['users'][$i]->screen_name. "\""." target=\"_blank\" >" ."<b>".$followers['users'][$i]->screen_name."</b>"."</a><br/>";
          echo "</p>";
          echo "<p class=\"desc\">". $followers['users'][$i]->description . "<p>";
          echo "<p class=\"info\">"."Seguidores : ".$followers['users'][$i]->followers_count ." "."Siguiendo : ".$followers['users'][$i]->friends_count." "."Tweets : ".$followers['users'][$i]->statuses_count ;
          } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

increment the cursor

```
$nextCursor = $reply->next_cursor_str;

while ($nextCursor > 0) {

$followers= (array) $reply;


 for($i=0;$i<count($followers) ;$i++){
          echo "<p>";
          echo "<img src=\"". $followers['users'][$i]->profile_image_url. "\" />";
          echo "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/". $followers['users'][$i]->screen_name. "\""." target=\"_blank\" >" ."<b>".$followers['users'][$i]->screen_name."</b>"."</a><br/>";
          echo "</p>";
          echo "<p class=\"desc\">". $followers['users'][$i]->description . "<p>";
          echo "<p class=\"info\">"."Seguidores : ".$followers['users'][$i]->followers_count ." "."Siguiendo : ".$followers['users'][$i]->friends_count." "."Tweets : ".$followers['users'][$i]->statuses_count ;
          } 


$reply= $cb->followers_list('cursor=' . $nextCursor);

$nextCursor = $reply->next_cursor_str;

}
```

Comment: It might make sense to use the cursors in a loop. Watch out, though, not to send more than the allowed number of requests to followers/list per rate-limit timeframe, or else you will hit your rate-limit.